# Would someone be able provide an example of what an AWS Cloudformation AWS::GLUE::WORKFLOW template would look like?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

I have been searching for an example of how to set up Cloudformation for a glue workflow which includes triggers, jobs, and crawlers, but I haven't been able to find much information on it.

This is the only piece of information I am able to find from AWS

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::Glue::Workflow",
  "Properties" : {
      "DefaultRunProperties" : Json,
      "Description" : String,
      "Name" : String,
      "Tags" : Json
    }
}
```

Comment: All the various cloudformation bits for Glue are [documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_Glue.html). Then there is [non-CF documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/creating_running_workflows.html) for how to put it all together. If you know how to do it from the console then you should be able to implement the various bits in CF. So what exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: https://old.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/df98zj/would_someone_be_able_provide_an_example_of_what/

Comment: thats mine but thank you!

Comment: @404 Unhelpful and unnecessary, AWS' documentation for Glue workflows suck. Also, the notion that anyone who knows how to do something in the console can easily translate it to CFT is laughable

Answer (score 12):

Here's an example of a workflow with one crawler and a job to be run after the crawler finishes.

It is defined through tagging the triggers with the **WorkflowName**.

I believe there can be only one SCHEDULED or ON_DEMAND trigger to start the workflow. All the other triggers in the workflow need to be CONDITIONAL on the jobs / crawlers. That's probably how CloudFormation knows how to build the DAG.

Also see how the workflow parameters are defined as a json in the **DefaultRunProperties**.

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Parameters:
  BaseBucket:
    Description: Bucket used by my workflow jobs
    Type: String

Resources:
  MyWorkflow:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Workflow
    Properties: 
      DefaultRunProperties:
        {
          "workflowParameter1": "Foo",
          "workflowParameter2": "Bar",
          "bucket": { "Fn::Sub": "${BaseBucket}" }
        }
      Description: Workflow for orchestrating my jobs
      Name: MyWorkflowName

  WorkflowCrawler:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Crawler
    Properties:
      Name: MyCrawler
      Role: MyCrawlerRole
      Description: A crawler to run as the first step in the workflow
      DatabaseName: MyDatabase
      Targets:
        S3Targets:
          - Path: !Sub "s3://${BaseBucket}/"

  WorkflowJob:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Job
    Properties:
      Description: Glue job to run after the crawler
      Name: MyWorkflowJob
      Role: MyJobRole
      Command:
        Name: pythonshell
        PythonVersion: 3
        ScriptLocation: !Sub "s3://${BaseBucket}/my_workflow_job_script.py"

  WorkflowStartTrigger:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Trigger
    Properties:
      Name: StartTrigger
      Type: ON_DEMAND
      Description: Trigger for starting the workflow
      Actions:
        - CrawlerName: !Ref WorkflowCrawler
      WorkflowName: !Ref MyWorkflow

  WorkflowJobTrigger:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Trigger
    Properties:
      Name: CrawlerSuccessfulTrigger
      Type: CONDITIONAL
      StartOnCreation: True
      Description: Trigger to start the glue job
      Actions:
        - JobName: !Ref WorkflowJob
      Predicate:
        Conditions:
          - LogicalOperator: EQUALS
            CrawlerName: !Ref WorkflowCrawler
            CrawlState: SUCCEEDED
      WorkflowName: !Ref MyWorkflow
```

Comment: How to we pass "DefaultRunProperties" as parameter here?

Comment: @AWS_Lernar They're passed as properties for the Workflow resource: 
`Properties: 
      DefaultRunProperties:
        {
          "workflowParameter1": "Foo",
          "workflowParameter2": "Bar",
          "bucket": { "Fn::Sub": "${BaseBucket}" }
        }`

Comment: I understand that but my question was how to pass them as parameters not in template itself so that i can dynamically change them while deploying the template.

Comment: Do you mean Cloud Formation Parameters: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html ?

Comment: Yes. But when i am passing DefaultRunProperties as as json parameter i am getting "internal error."

Comment: Can you show an example of how you're trying to pass the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a Glue workflow using triggers, crawlers and a job to convert JSON to Parquet:

```
JSONtoParquetWorkflow:
  Type: AWS::Glue::Workflow
  Properties: 
    Name: json-to-parquet-workflow
    Description: Workflow for orchestrating JSON to Parquet conversion
RawJSONCrawlerTrigger:
  Type: AWS::Glue::Trigger
  Properties:
    WorkflowName: !Ref JSONtoParquetWorkflow
    Name: raw-json-crawler-trigger
    Description: Start crawler for raw JSON data
    Type: ON_DEMAND
    Actions:
      - CrawlerName: !Ref RawJSONCrawler
JSONToParquetETLJobTrigger:
  Type: AWS::Glue::Trigger
  Properties:
    WorkflowName: !Ref JSONtoParquetWorkflow
    Name: json-to-parquet-etl-trigger
    Description: Start JSON to Parquet ETL job
    Type: CONDITIONAL
    StartOnCreation: True
    Predicate:
      Conditions:
        - LogicalOperator: EQUALS
          CrawlerName: !Ref RawJSONCrawler
          CrawlState: SUCCEEDED
    Actions:
      - JobName: !Ref JSONToParquetETLJob
RawParquetCrawlerTrigger:
  Type: AWS::Glue::Trigger
  Properties:
    WorkflowName: !Ref JSONtoParquetWorkflow
    Name: raw-parquet-crawler-trigger
    Description: Start crawler for raw Parquet data
    Type: CONDITIONAL
    StartOnCreation: True
    Predicate:
      Conditions:
        - LogicalOperator: EQUALS
          JobName: !Ref JSONToParquetETLJob
          State: SUCCEEDED
    Actions:
      - CrawlerName: !Ref RawParquetCrawler
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple example to find, therefore I created an example [AWS Glue Workflow: Getting started](https://ojitha.blogspot.com/2021/06/aws-glue-workflow-getting-started.html#fn2) which is using AWS Cloudformation template. This example is very easy but explained with diagrams.